# OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener service not starting in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, listener, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2, tns

I am using Windows 10.

I have installed Oracle Database 11g Release 2(11.2). Also configured LISTENER.

I installed a new database connection through sqlplus. I am able to connect to the database coonection using sqlplus. However, when I configure the same connection using SQL developer, I am getting "**Status: Failure - Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**".

I tried **lsnrctl status**. I found this.

TNS-12541: TNS: no listener
    TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
        TNS-00511: No listener
            64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
            Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=MYKEY1521)))

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
    TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
        TNS-00511: No listener
            64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory

I tried **lsnrctl start**. I found this.

TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
    TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

I tried removing and reinstalling the LISTENER from Oracle Net Configuration Assistant. But I am getting the error as mentioned above.

Also the following service are running in my system.

1. OracleService(SID)
2. OracleRemExecService
3. OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent
4. OracleMTSRecoveryService
5. OracleJobScheduler(SID)
6. Oracle (SID) Writer Service

However the service **OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener is not getting listed** (not getting started either).
The problem is around OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener service.

Can anyone please let me know how to get OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener service up and stable so that the database connection is established  using sql developer.